# duplicate in list<list<String>> java

Tags: java

I have  problem in find duplicate in list.

```
[[I1, I2, I5], [I1, I2, I3], [I1, I2, I5], [I1, I2, I3], [I1, I5, I2], [I1, I3, I2]]
```

I want to remove same subset from my list.

```
for(int i=0;i<ProdSetSuport3.size()-1;i++){
    for(int j=i+1;j<ProdSetSuport3.size();j++){
        List<List<String>> tmpSet = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        if(!ProdSetSuport3.get(j).contains(ProdSetSuport3.get(i).get(0))
           && ProdSetSuport3.get(j).contains(ProdSetSuport3.get(i).get(1))
           && ProdSetSuport3.get(j).contains(ProdSetSuport3.get(i).get(2)))
        {
            tmpSet.add(ProdSetSuport3.get(j));
        }
    }
}
```

I try to use HashSet but HashSet can't remove!

Please help me!

Comment: What's is the issue with above code?  What output are you getting vs expecting?

Comment: Logically seems that should work, try removing `!` in `if(!ProdSetsupport3...`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please take the [tour] and visit our [help] to learn what kinds of questions are appropriate for this site.  If you can [edit] your question to fit the requirements of this site, please do so.

Comment: i write these code but cant take a right out .the same subset dont remove from my list how i can remove same subset you can see i have three subset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HashSet` seems to work with `List` items too:

```
List<List<String>> lists=Arrays.asList(
        Arrays.asList("I1", "I2", "I5"),
        Arrays.asList("I1", "I2", "I3"),
        Arrays.asList("I1", "I2", "I5"),
        Arrays.asList("I1", "I2", "I3"),
        Arrays.asList("I1", "I5", "I2"),
        Arrays.asList("I1", "I3", "I2")
);
List<List<String>> filtered=new ArrayList<>();
List<List<String>> duplicates=new ArrayList<>();
HashSet<List<String>> filter=new HashSet<>();
for(List<String> list: lists){
  if(!filter.contains(list)){
    filter.add(list);
    filtered.add(list);
  } else {
    duplicates.add(list);
  }
}
System.out.println("Original: "+lists);
System.out.println("Filtered: "+filtered);
System.out.println("Duplicates: "+duplicates);
System.out.println("(Filter: "+filter+")");
```

Output:

> ```
> Original: [[I1, I2, I5], [I1, I2, I3], [I1, I2, I5], [I1, I2, I3], [I1, I5, I2], [I1, I3, I2]]
> Filtered: [[I1, I2, I5], [I1, I2, I3], [I1, I5, I2], [I1, I3, I2]]
> Duplicates: [[I1, I2, I5], [I1, I2, I3]]
> (Filter: [[I1, I3, I2], [I1, I5, I2], [I1, I2, I5], [I1, I2, I3]])
> ```

"Original" line is the same what you wrote
"Filtered" line has the duplicates removed
"Duplicates" line shows that the duplicate elements were collected properly
"(Filter)" line shows that if you need the filtered set of elements only and do not need an actual list, the `HashSet` itself already contains the result (and using `LinkedHashSet` even preserves the original order). For getting this line only, you can use a simple loop, `for(List<String> list: lists) filter.add(list);`

---

If the input should be considered as a "set of sets", the inner-list can be converted into a set too:

```
HashSet<HashSet<String>> filter=new HashSet<>();
for(List<String> list: lists){
  HashSet<String> key=new HashSet<>(list);
  if(!filter.contains(key)){
    filter.add(key);
    filtered.add(list);
  } else {
    duplicates.add(list);
  }
}
```

Output becomes:

> ```
> Original: [[I1, I2, I5], [I1, I2, I3], [I1, I2, I5], [I1, I2, I3], [I1, I5, I2], [I1, I3, I2]]
> Filtered: [[I1, I2, I5], [I1, I2, I3]]
> Duplicates: [[I1, I2, I5], [I1, I2, I3], [I1, I5, I2], [I1, I3, I2]]
> (Filter: [[I1, I2, I3], [I1, I2, I5]])
> ```

This one is correct as long as the triplets do not contain duplicates (e.g. the inner `HashSet` is going to be `L1-L2` for both `L1-L1-L2` and `L1-L2-L2`, marking one of them as duplicate). If that would be a valid case, I would suggest creating an ordered copy of the lists and use that as key.

Comment: Thank for guid. but [l1,I2,I5] AND [I1,I5,I2] are same i want to keep just one of them

Answer (score 0):

Try  this compatible java8+

```
HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

List<String> dupicateList = new ArrayList<>();

for (List<String> innerList : ProdSetSuport3) {
  innerList.forEach(value -> {
    if (set.contains(value)) {
      dupicateList.add(value);
    } else {
      set.add(value);
    }
  });
}
```

dupicateList contains all the duplicates.

Comment: No. My java is 7 cant use this one